# What is the best way to get sorted SQL query based on null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database which i want to extract data in a specific order.
Here is an example of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `field1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `field1_2` (`field1`,`field2`),
  UNIQUE KEY `field1_3` (`field1`,`field3`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Valid entries in my table is:

- field1 must be filled
- field2 can be either null or an unique value based on field1 and field2
- field3 can be either null or an uniqie value based on field1 and field3

The order i want to extract the data is:

- all fields with field2 and field3 as null
- all fields with field2 as null and field3 with values
- all fields with field3 as null and field2 with values

So far i have used three queries connected with UNION

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE field2 IS NULL 
    AND field3 IS NULL UNION
SELECT * FROM test WHERE field2 IS NULL 
    AND field3 IS NOT NULL UNION 
SELECT * FROM test WHERE field2 IS NOT NULL 
    AND field3 IS NULL;
```

I myself feel this is to much necessary code to get it in order and hoped there was a better solution.

So is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your conditions into a single `order by`:

```
order by (field2 is null and field3 is null) desc,
         (field2 is null and field3 is not null) desc,
         (field2 is null and field3 is not null) desc
```

You might want to add a `where` as well:

```
where field2 is null or field3 is null
```

This works because MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context, with "true" as 1 and "false" as 0.  This is why the `desc` is needed.  You can express the same thing in standard SQL as:

```
order by (case when field2 is null and field3 is null then 1
               when field2 is null and field3 is not null then 2
               when field2 is not null and field3 is null then 3
               else 4
          end)
```